# IBM Watson Studio: Convert an ibmdbpy.frame.IdaDataFrame to pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science-experience, watson-studio

I have a problem with the `ibmdbpy.frame.IdaDataFrame` type in IBM Watson Studio.

I have two dataframes. The first of type `ibmdbpy.frame.IdaDataFrame` and the second of type `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

I would like to merge these two dataframes in Python.

Is it possible to convert an `ibmdbpy.frame.IdaDataFrame` to `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`?

Comment: I see this is your first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can see what you have tried and better understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the dataframe of type `ibmdbpy.frame.IdaDataFrame` to `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` by using:

```
ida_df.as_dataframe()
```

Where, `ida_df` will be your dataframe of type `ibmdbpy.frame.IdaDataFrame`. This returns an object of type `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` which you can then merge with your second dataframe.